# Unable to update data by Eloquent in Laravel, phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am developing an application using Laravel, Eloquent as ORM, phpunit for unit testing. But i am not able to update data in database. Though there is no exception, warning or error. If the object of the model class checked in laravel, before update and after update, it is showing that data has been changed in the model class but when checking the database, found that data is not being changed.

**Model Class**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = "posts";

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'title',
        'description',
        'total_needed',
        'total_collected',
        'total_expanse',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
        'active',
        'updated_at',
        'created_at',
    ];
}//class
```

**Repository Code**

```
class Post_Repo_Impl implements Post_Repo_I
{
    public function update(Post $postUpdate)
    {
        $raedOld = false;
        $updateStatus = false;
        try {
            $psot_id = $postUpdate->id;
            $postOrgin = Post::find($psot_id);
            $raedOld = true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log("Post Update : failed to read existig post.");
        }
        if ($raedOld) {
            try {
                 //line 1
                echo "\n" . $postOrgin->title . "\n";
                $this->setPostValues($postOrgin, $postUpdate)->update();
                 //line 2
                echo "\n" . $postOrgin->title . "\n";
                $updateStatus = true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                error_log("Post Update : Failed to save updated post." . "\n\n" . $e);
            }
        }
        return  $updateStatus;
    } //update
}
```

Line 1 and Line 2, not printing same value. Line 2 printing the changed value.

**Unit Test code**

```
class RepoPost extends TestCase
{
    public function testMain()
    {
        echo "\n >----------- Test Main : ---------> \n";
        $this->postUpdate();
    } //mother test

    public function postUpdate()
    {
        $postDummyUpdate = new Post();
        $postDummyUpdate->id = '2';
        $postDummyUpdate->user_id = 'Tst';
        $postDummyUpdate->title = 'Post Updated Repo Test........';
        $postDummyUpdate->description = 'UnitTesting of URLs';
        $postDummyUpdate->total_needed = '2000';
        $postDummyUpdate->total_collected = '1000';
        $postDummyUpdate->total_expanse = '500';
        $postDummyUpdate->start_date = '22-09-2019';
        $postDummyUpdate->end_date = '22-10-2019';
        $postDummyUpdate->active = '1';
        $postDummyUpdate->updated_at = '2019-09-24';
        $postDummyUpdate->created_at = '2019-09-22';

        echo '\n----PostUpdate----\n';
        $postRepoSave = $this->getRepoPostImpl();
        dd($postRepoSave->update($postDummyUpdate));
        if ($postRepoSave == false) {
            error_log("\n\nTest : Data Save Failed.");
        } else {
            error_log("Saved Post ID : " . $postRepoSave);
        }
    }

    public function getRepoPostImpl()
    {
        return new Post_Repo_Impl();
    }
}
```

In the test code it is returning true.

Comment: Updating Data in the Database in an unit Test ist Not an unit test.

Comment: @CaddyDZ, can u do any help?

Comment: You already asked this question yesterday and I already answered